# Is it possible to create a Thread that runs every 0.1 seconds? what are the consequences?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm trying to create a Thread that runs every 0.1 seconds.
A lot of app animations that require a very short time update - What they using?

Perform it with a simple `timer` will be a good solution? I'm wondering about the performance and CPU usage.

I would like to create my own animations, that requires that kind of refresh, there is any best practice for that?

Comment: The right answer will depend a lot on why you want to run a method every 0.1 seconds and what that method will do.

Comment: To add the CommonsWare's answer, the factors that affect the choice are: 1) do you need precisely 0.1s, or _at least_ 0.1s? 2) how much resources (including CPU time) will the operation consume? What must happen if the operation does not complete in 0.1s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are seeking solution as `NSTimer` in iOS, then that's the same as

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Your code here
                }
            }, 0, 100);
```

This will fire every 100 milliseconds + CPU time in run method

Comment: The app has crashed..

Comment: ? can you provide stacktrace and reason

Comment: what? here is the code:

Comment: new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
             circle.setX(circleX + 10);
             circle.setY(circleY + 10);
            }
        }, 0, 100);

Comment: you said app crashed, so crash usually crash generates stacktrace and reason. so please provide that information.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what `currentRunLoop` in your code is.

I don't know how iOS handles multiple threads but in Android you must not touch the UI from background threads. Repeated tasks are almost always about modifying the UI in some way.

Assuming that iOS has a special loop that is allowed to modify the UI and `currentRunLoop` is exactly that (compare [`Looper.getMainLooper()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#getMainLooper%28%29)):

You need to schedule events within Android's main thread. To do so, you will need to use a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) attached to that main thread.

To schedule repeating tasks you would most likely use one of `Handler`'s `...Delayed` methods with a delay of 100ms to schedule your code at the desired rate. You can alternatively use an infinitely running [`CountDownTimer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) that does exactly this already.

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(Long.MAX_VALUE, 100) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // Do Something Here
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() { /* won't happen */ };
}
timer.start();
```

The one thing you should **not** use in this case (and I've pretty much never found a valid use for it in Android) is [`java.util.Timer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) since that executes code in a background tread. You can use it if for some reason your repeated task needs to be executed in background, like for example a http request.

Comment: its work just one time..

Comment: @NirGofman it should do something every 100ms, can you add some (Android) code to your question so we can understand how you're using all this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
m_handler = new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Do what you want
        m_handler.run();
    }

}, 100);
```

Let me know if it work for you.

Comment: it gives an error: m_handler cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: and this error: m_handler cannot be resolved

Comment: You should declare m_handler like this: `Handler m_handler`

Comment: steal not work's: type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to Handler

Comment: Ok..trying to change approach..why CountDownTimer not works for you? How many times you have to repeat that method?

Comment: If you have to repeat forever you should considering to use a Service that run in background with CountDownTimer. In onFinish method just call timer.start() for restart timer when it finishes